# dotnet publish cmd with profile not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, publish, asp.net-core-2.1, dotnet-publish

I'm trying to publish an aspnetcore 2.1 webapi application through cmd using an ftp profile.
When I publish through vs2017, it works fine.
But when I try to do it by command line it is not sent to the ftp server.
It publishes in the \bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\publish\

I was wondering if I'm doing something wrong?

I've tried this:

```
dotnet publish aspnetcore.devops.example.api.csproj /p:PublishProfile="Properties\PublishProfiles\FtpProfile.pubxml"
```

This:

```
dotnet publish aspnetcore.devops.example.api.csproj /p:PublishProfile="Properties\PublishProfiles\FtpProfile.pubxml" /p:Password="myFtpPass@123"
```

And this:

```
dotnet publish aspnetcore.devops.example.api.csproj /p:PublishProfile="Properties\PublishProfiles\FtpProfile.pubxml"  /p:Username="myFtpUser" /p:Password="myFtpPass@123"
```